# Move Cursor in EditText: i have created a button that can move the cursor up ,down, left , right. i have no idea to make up and down

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext, cursor

```
 public void onClick (View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnUp) {
            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnDown) {
                int start = txtInput.getSelectionStart();
                int haha = start / 2;
                int hehe = haha / 2;
                int samp = haha + hehe;
                Log.e("up", samp + "");
                if (start >= 1 && samp >= 1) {
                    txtInput.setSelection(samp);
                    Log.e("up", samp + "");
                }
            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLeft) {
                int start = txtInput.getSelectionStart();
                if (start >= 1) {
                    txtInput.setSelection(start - 1);
                    Log.e("left", start + "");
                }
            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRight) {
                int start = txtInput.getSelectionStart();
                if (start < txtInput.length()) {
                    txtInput.setSelection(start + 1);
                    Log.e("right", start + "");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: any one have an idea to make this work, to make up and down work?

Comment: Please give a [mcve].